# Query against JSON array elements?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to run queries on array elements? Seems like it works ok on the top level items... Lets say I have this json:

```
{
  "_id": "5769cfbf7e45b52e388bbc78",
  "address": {
    "street": "2 Avenue",
    "zipcode": "10075",
    "building": "1480",
    "coord": [
      73.9557413,
      40.7720266
    ]
  },
  "borough": "Manhattan",
  "cuisine": "Italian",
  "grades": [
    {
      "date": "2014-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 11
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
      "grade": "B",
      "score": 17
    }
  ],
  "name": "Vella",
  "restaurant_id": "41704620"
}
```

Is it possible to use JSON_QUERY / JSON_VALUE to do a where clause against grades[xxx].score? I.e. I want to return all documents where ANY of the grades.score is >= 17.

Comment: I think you want to use [`OPENJSON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921879.aspx). I don't have SQL Server 2016 available, so I can't really help any further than that.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Azure and SQL Server 2016 supports JSON natively now. You can use the following query in '`EXISTS`' clause, or whatever is needed (assuming `@json` contains the given JSON data):

```
SELECT g.score as score
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (Id varchar(max)) j
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.grades')) WITH (score int) AS g
WHERE g.score = 17
```

Comment: SQL Azure and **SQL Server 2016** supports JSON natively.